# spring boot 2.6.6 not loading static data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have spring boot application and getting 404 error to load static pages like css,images,js
Placed these files under src/main/resources/static/css, src/main/resources/static/js etc..

tried multiple options and currently Below options have in my code
applicaiton.yml file

```
mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER    
    static-path-pattern: /static/**
 web:
   resources:
    static-locations: classpath:/static/
```

Java Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    
    String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {"classpath:/resources/","classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/static/images"};
    

     @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/**");    
        }
}
```